# Null restriction in sql in operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a query to fetch multiple column data for many rows at once.

Table 1. No null value

```
customer, price1, price2, price3, ..., price10
Tata,     100,    200,    300,    ..., 1000
Ford,     111,    222,    333,    ..., 1388
```

I can use below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (customer,price1,price2,price3,...~price10)
IN (
(Tata,100,200,300,400,500,..~1000)
OR
(Ford,111,222,333,444,555,...~1388)
```

Table 2:

```
consumer_code, price1, price2, price3, price4, …, price10
Chn,           100,    200,    (null), (null), …, 600
Hyd,           121,    378,    262,    (null), …, (null)
```

SQL where in operator doesn't accept null values.
Any suggestions for a better query?

I need to pass bulk data say >500 or 1000 at once so as to reduce multiple db operations by using multiple select statements and improve the retrieval speed.

Comment: I don't get the logic - are you saying you only want rows where there is an exact match so for example if chn had 20 in price 3 it should not appear or are you saying if all of the non null columns match then the row should appear?

Comment: Note that a database table is not a spreadsheet. Seriously consider whether your present schema is fit for purpose. (Hint: it isn't)

Comment: @P.Salmon    Yes, I need the rows where there is an exact match. Combination of all the columns

Comment: @strawberry my schema need to support this. I need to pass spreadsheet values and validate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sql where in operator doesn't accept null values. Any suggestions for a better query?

The `in` operator *does* accept `NULL` values.  It simply does not consider them to be equal.

You can use the `NULL`-safe comparison, `<=>` instead of `IN`:

```
where (customer_code <=> 'Tata' and price1 <=> 100 and . . .
      ) or
      (customer_code <=> 'Ford' and price1 <=> 111 and . . .
      ) or
```

You can include `NULL` for the values.

This also works with tuples, so:

```
where (customer, price1, price2, price3,... ~price10)
<=> ('Tata', 100, 200, 300, 400, 500,.. ~1000) or
      (customer, price1, price2, price3,... ~price10) <=> ( . . . ) or
       . . .
```

Comment: Hi Lintoff                                                     It almost similar to            where( (customer = 'Tata', price1=100, price2=200,price3=300) or (customer='Tata',price1 IS NULL, price2 IS NULL, price3=400) ).                                  Your query would be good if we mention columns at once and values as tuples

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an exact match to your input you could use a sub query for the input and join to the main table

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t
(mid varchar(3), p1 int,p2 int,p3 int);

insert into t values
('frd',1,2,3),
('frd',1,2,5),
('frd',1,null,3),
('chn',1,2,3);

select t.* 
from t
join (select cast('frd' as char(3)) mid, 1 p1,null p2,3 p3
        union
        select 'chn',1,2,3) s 
on  s.mid = t.mid and
        coalesce(s.p1,-1) = coalesce(t.p1,-1) and 
        coalesce(s.p2,-1)   = coalesce(t.p2,-1) and 
        coalesce(s.p3,-1)   = coalesce(t.p3,-1);


+------+------+------+------+
| mid  | p1   | p2   | p3   |
+------+------+------+------+
| frd  |    1 | NULL |    3 |
| chn  |    1 |    2 |    3 |
+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You may get collation issues. It might be easier long term to create a table to hold your conditions and use that instead of a sub query.

Comment: It works. Thanks for your contribution.  But I didn't get the point about collation issues and how creating a separate table would help. If possible could you explain in brief or any link which provides related info.   Is it safe to pass too many inner select values say around 500 at once?